# Adding new patches to a matplotlib plot while an animation is occurring (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

Does anyone know how to add patches to a plot within a function call? It seems that I can only add a new patch outside of a call and not within one. Here is my code and I know the function is being executed because of the print statement but the new patch doesn't get added:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6.25)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 138), ylim=(0, 79))
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((9, 1), 120, 1))
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((9, 77), 120, 1))

rect = patches.Rectangle((xa3-6, ya4+0.75), 12, 12)
def upRamp(newPatch):
    global ax
    print "Ramp"
    ax.add_patch(newPatch)

upRamp(rect)
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds the patch to ax just fine on my machine. If you hadn't checked already, you can determine whether the patch has been added by inspecting:

```
print(ax.patches)
```

In your code snippet you haven't defined xa3 or ya4 - I would hazard a guess that they might have taken values that mean your patch "rect" lies outside of the plotting area defined by xlim and ylim.

Comment: This was for my senior project in college, and I must have found an answer or I wouldn't have graduated, but I cannot for the life of me remember most of this. I appreciate your help though, David! I wasn't on top of this enough then to respond.